# Impossible to change one-page checkout step to payment on magento 1.9.3.6

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I'm stucked on the 4th step on one page checkout, I can't continue to next step on shipping to payment.

The button reacts, ajax call is fine, returned content seems perfect, but it doesn't execute or fill on HTML.

I was read about that issue on more topics like the following:

- [Magento V1.8 one page checkout not loading payment information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/magento-v1-8-one-page-checkout-not-loading-payment-information)
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/One-Page-Checkout-stuck-on-step-4-payment/m-p/21868#M1903
- [Cant continue past shipping when in Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/cant-continue-past-shipping-when-in-checkout)
- [Magento 1.9 checkout stuck on shipping methods](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50179/magento-1-9-checkout-stuck-on-shipping-methods)

But no success. I also read and try another posts, but the same result.

The problem is that when I click continue on shipping information, the payment is not loaded but ajax request do.

JSON returns the following:

```
"goto_section": "payment",
"update_section": {
    "name": "payment_method",
    "html": '<dt id="dt_method_cashondelivery">            <input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Contrarreembolso" onclick="payment.switchMethod('cashondelivery')" class="radio" />            <label for="p_method_cashondelivery">Contrarreembolso </label>    </dt>        <dt id="dt_method_purchaseorder">            <input id="p_method_purchaseorder" value="purchaseorder" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Purchase Order" onclick="payment.switchMethod('purchaseorder')" class="radio" />            <label for="p_method_purchaseorder">Purchase Order </label>    </dt>        <dd id="dd_method_purchaseorder">        <ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_purchaseorder" style="display:none;">    <li>        <label for="po_number" class="required"><em>*</em>Número de la orden de compra</label>        <div class="input-box">            <input type="text" id="po_number" name="payment[po_number]" title="Número de la orden de compra" class="input-text required-entry" value="" />        </div>    </li></ul>    </dd>    <script type="text/javascript">    //<![CDATA[        payment.init();        //]]></script>'
}
```

Seems that `payment.init()` doesn't execute never because it doesn't enter on debugger on that function, but if I execute `payment.init()` manually on console the result is the same even entering on the javascript function successfully.

Doesn't matter if I change `checkout.xml`, `info.phtml`, `methods.phtml`, and more files, the problem is the same (all seems correct, no errors, good information retrieving but not success on step change).

If I change to the default template, the error persists, but the right column with the order resume updates correctly, when if I configure my custom template it doesn't, but the step to request payment information is always unaccessible.

Please, can you put some light on this?

Thank you.

### EDIT

I can add more information. On `/var/log/exceptions.log` I can see:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'El tipo de bloque es inválido: ' in /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('El tipo de bloq...')
#1 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'root')
#3 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'root')
#4 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(212): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#8 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction()
#9 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#10 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/marcosprog/httpd/foruzz/web/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

But I don't know what and why the block is invalid, so shipping loads fine and also payment json.

### Note

Note that the payment information loads fine, if I remove `display: none` from `<div id="checkout-step-payment">` I can see all options and fine, so I guess there is a problem on the javascript that show this part of the page.

### Solved

I add an answer and will be accepted today, but if someone has a better solution I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solve the problem. It was a javascript problem, not a php or block problem.

On the file `opcheckout.js` we can found this piece of code (line 650 aprox)

```
    if (response.update_section) {
        $('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
    }
```

But the problem is that `$('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load')` element doesn't exists, because `response.update_section.name = "payment_method"` where needs to be `response.update_section.name = "payment-method"` (semicolon).

I don't know why PHP returns `payment_method` instead of `payment-method` that is the correct element, or maybe is a problem on the Meigee Theme that I am using.

However, to avoid problems on php, I solve it on the javascript changing the above code for this piece:

```
    if (response.update_section) {
        var sect = (response.update_section.name === "payment_method") ? "payment-method" : response.update_section.name;
        $('checkout-'+sect+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
    }
```

Only for `payment-method` and all is OK right now, I can complete the checkout process with no problem.

If you know another method to solve this problem, please, add an answer and it will be accepted.